# Calculator using variable names

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, math-expression-eval, symbolic-math

I've recently been assigned an assignment to create a word calculator, and given my knowledge in python is still quite lacking, I want to ask if anybody has any better ideas for any possible solutions.

The question is here:

> Jimmy has invented a new kind of calculator that works with words
> rather than numbers.
>
> - Input is read from stdin and consists of up to 1000 commands, one
>   per    line.
> - Each command is a definition, a calculation or `clear`.
> - All tokens within a command are separated by single spaces.
> - A definition has the format `def x y` where x is a variable name and y    is an integer in the range [-1000, 1000].
> - Existing definitions are replaced by new ones i.e. if x has been    defined previously, defining x again erases its old definition.
> - Variable names consist of 1-30 lowercase characters.
> - No two variables are ever defined to have the same value at the
>   same    time.
> - The `clear` command erases all existing variable definitions.
> - A calculation command starts with the word `calc`, and is followed
>   by    one or more variable names separated by addition or subtraction
>   operators.
> - The end of a calculation command is an equals sign.
>
> The goal is to write a program for Jimmy's calculator. Some rules are:
>
> - The program should produce no output for definitions, but for    calculations it should output the value of the calculation.
> - Where there is no word for the result, or some word in a calculation    has not been defined, then the output should be
>   `unknown`. (The word    `unknown` is never used as a variable name.)
> - Your solution may only import content from the `sys` module.
> - Your solution may not use the `eval()` function.
>
> Here is a sample input below:
>
> ```
> calc foo + bar =
> def bar 7
> def programming 10
> calc foo + bar =
> def is 4
> def fun 8
> calc programming - is + fun =
> def fun 1
> calc programming - is + fun =
> clear
> ```
>
> And the corresponding output:
>
> ```
> foo + bar = unknown
> foo + bar = programming
> programming - is + fun = unknown
> programming - is + fun = bar
> ```

My current solution is this:

```
import sys
lines = sys.stdin.readlines()

d_define = {}
numsInDict = []
operators = ["+", "-", "="]

# IN : word to checked it is in the dictionary
# OUT : returns unknown or value for word
def lookup(word):
    if word in d_define:
        return d_define[word]
    else:
        return "unknown"

# IN : answer to check if there is a word assigned to it a dictionary
# OUT : returns unknown or word assigned to answer
def getAnswer(answer):
    for k, v in d_define.items():
        if v == answer:
            return k
    return "unknown"

# IN : All values to calc (includes operators)
# OUT : print unknown or word if in dict
def calc(args):
    equation = 0
    lastOperator = "+"
    for word in args:
        if word not in operators:
            res = lookup(word)
            if res == "unknown":
                return "unknown"
            else:
                #print(res)
                if lastOperator == "+":
                    equation += res
                else:
                    equation -= res
        else:
            lastOperator = word
    if equation in numsInDict:
        res = getAnswer(equation)
        return res
    else:
        return "unknown"

# IN : word to be added and its value
# OUT : updated dictionary
def define(word, num):
    num = int(num)
    if num in numsInDict or word in d_define:
        # print(f'NEEDS REPLACE')
        # print(f'same value -> {num in numsInDict}')
        # print(f'same word -> {word in d_define}')
        # print(f'same word -> {d_define}')
        # print(f'same word -> {numsInDict}')
        topop = ""
        for k, v in d_define.items():
            if k == word:
                d_define[word] = num  # Update Word with new value
            elif v == num:
                topop = k  # Saves value to pop later
        if topop != "":
            d_define.pop(topop)
            d_define[word] = num
    else:
        d_define[word] = num
        numsInDict.append(num)
    #print(f'{word} - {d_define[word]}')

for line in lines:
    #print(f'-------------------------------------- LOOP START ------------------------------------')
    line = line.rstrip().split()
    #print(f'Line Split - {line}')
    if len(line) == 3 and line[0] == "def":
        define(line[1], line[2])
    elif len(line) > 1 and line[len(line) - 1] == "=":
        result = calc(line[1:])
        print(f'{" ".join(line[1:]) + " " + result}')
    elif len(line) == 1 and line[0] == "clear":
        d_define = {}
        wordsInDict = []
        numsInDict = []
        #print(f'Cleared d_define - {d_define} {wordsInDict}')
    #print(d_define)
    #print(f'--------------------------------------- LOOP END -------------------------------------')
```

It does feel quite clunky but it gets the job done. I am just wondering if anybody has any better ways in which it could be improved upon.

Comment: There's at least one reference to this online, at [Chegg](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/jimmy-invented-new-kind-calculator-works-words-rather-numbers-input-read-stdin-consists-10-q69093526). What is the original source?

Comment: It feels a bit odd that an unparseable line doesn't throw an error

Answer (score 8):

I think your solution does work, but it's very long-winded. Your `IN:`  and `OUT:`  comments should be moved to docstrings `""" """` in the first line of the function body.

`getAnswer` should be `get_answer` by PEP8.

Your `getAnswer` doesn't need to loop if you maintain an inverse dictionary of values to names.

Consider using the built-in `operator.add` and `.sub`. This violates the letter (though perhaps not the spirit) of *Your solution may only import content from the sys module*; if that's actually a problem just define the `add` and `sub` functions yourself.

You should just delete your LOOP START and LOOP END comments.

Consider writing unit tests to validate your output. This can be done by operating on the `stdin` and `stdout` streams passed as parameters, or yielding lines.

### Suggested

```
from operator import add, sub
from typing import Iterable, Iterator


def rewritten(in_stream: Iterable[str]) -> Iterator[str]:
    OPS = {'+': add, '-': sub}
    state, inverse_state = {}, {}

    for line in in_stream:
        command, *args = line.split()

        if command == 'def':
            name, val = args
            val = int(val)
            state[name] = val
            inverse_state[val] = name

        elif command == 'clear':
            state.clear()
            inverse_state.clear()

        elif command == 'calc':
            result, *values = (state.get(name) for name in args[::2])

            if result is not None:
                for op, value in zip(args[1:-1:2], values):
                    if value is None:
                        result = None
                        break
                    result = OPS[op](result, value)

            prefix = line.rstrip().split(maxsplit=1)[1]
            result = inverse_state.get(result, 'unknown')
            yield f'{prefix} {result}'


def test() -> None:
    sample_in = (
'''def foo 3
calc foo + bar =
def bar 7
def programming 10
calc foo + bar =
def is 4
def fun 8
calc programming - is + fun =
def fun 1
calc programming - is + fun =
clear'''
    ).splitlines()

    actual = '\n'.join(rewritten(sample_in))

    assert actual == (
'''foo + bar = unknown
foo + bar = programming
programming - is + fun = unknown
programming - is + fun = bar'''
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

### Even more lookups

As @Stef suggests, it is possible to add a lookup for the command. It's awkward, because only one of the three functions actually produces a result. One way to express this is an unconditional outer `yield from`, and all functions as generators, only one being non-empty. I don't particularly recommend this; it's just a demonstration:

```
def rewritten(in_stream: Iterable[str]) -> Iterator[str]:
    def clear() -> Iterator[str]:
        state.clear()
        inverse_state.clear()
        return; yield

    def define(name: str, val: str) -> Iterator[str]:
        val = int(val)
        state[name] = val
        inverse_state[val] = name
        return; yield

    def calc(*args: str) -> Iterator[str]:
        result, *values = (state.get(name) for name in args[::2])

        if result is not None:
            for op, value in zip(args[1:-1:2], values):
                if value is None:
                    result = None
                    break
                result = OPS[op](result, value)

        prefix = line.rstrip().split(maxsplit=1)[1]
        result = inverse_state.get(result, 'unknown')
        yield f'{prefix} {result}'

    OPS = {'+': add, '-': sub}
    COMMANDS = {'clear': clear, 'def': define, 'calc': calc}
    state, inverse_state = {}, {}

    for line in in_stream:
        parts = line.split()
        command, *args = parts
        yield from COMMANDS[command](*args)
```

Or just use `Optional`s:

```
def rewritten(in_stream: Iterable[str]) -> Iterator[str]:
    def clear() -> Optional[str]:
        state.clear()
        inverse_state.clear()

    def define(name: str, val: str) -> Optional[str]:
        val = int(val)
        state[name] = val
        inverse_state[val] = name

    def calc(*args: str) -> Optional[str]:
        result, *values = (state.get(name) for name in args[::2])

        if result is not None:
            for op, value in zip(args[1:-1:2], values):
                if value is None:
                    result = None
                    break
                result = OPS[op](result, value)

        prefix = line.rstrip().split(maxsplit=1)[1]
        result = inverse_state.get(result, 'unknown')
        return f'{prefix} {result}'

    OPS = {'+': add, '-': sub}
    COMMANDS = {'clear': clear, 'def': define, 'calc': calc}
    state, inverse_state = {}, {}

    for line in in_stream:
        parts = line.split()
        command, *args = parts
        result = COMMANDS[command](*args)
        if result is not None:
            yield result
```

Comment: You suggest using a dictionary to map operator symbols to the corresponding operations, `OPS = {'+': add, '-': sub}`. I think that's a great idea. You could also use a dictionary to map commands `clear, def, calc` to functions. This way, you could encapsulate the code of the commands in functions, and avoid bogging the main loop of function `rewritten` with a huge `if/elif/else`.

Comment: @Stef I hesitate to think that a ~20-line if/elif is "huge". If it were larger I would agree.

Answer (score 5):

The reason your solution is convoluted is that the problem hamstringing you by not allowing *any* modules (except `sys`) including the built in ones!

Secondly it seems you need to freshen up on your basics. For instance this

```
def lookup(word):
    if word in d_define:
        return d_define[word]
    else:
        return "unknown"
```

Can be written as

```
d_define.get(word, "unknown")
```

Secondly `d_define` is a bad name; as a general rule avoid abbreviations in variable and function names. Assume that everything is fair game, no limitations on external libraries. The crux is that `eval` is really dangerous, and you should never run it on user input. For instance an user could import the `os` library and then run commands to delete your whole file system. However, there are safe ways to use it, for instance

```
    SAFE_CHARS = set("0123456789+-*(). /")

    for char in expr:
        if char not in SAFE_CHARS:
            value = "unknown"
            break
    else:
        value = eval(expr)
```

If we detect any "malicious intent", e.g anything other that mathematical expressions we break and return `"unknown"`. We first replace all the words with their values before evaluating. Some care is taken here for instance if we have "foobar=3" and "bar=2" then "foobar" must be replaced before "bar" otherwise we might end up with "foo2".

Note that this way of solving the problem is very slow with many definitions, but I really do not think speed matters.

```
import sys


SAFE_CHARS = set("0123456789+-*(). /")


class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.definitions = dict()
        self.values = dict()

    def definition(self, name: str, integer: float) -> None:
        self.definitions[name] = integer
        self.values[integer] = name

    def clear(self):
        self.definitions = dict()
        self.values = dict()

    def calculate(self, expr: str) -> float | str:
        expr = "".join(expr.split())  # Remove all spaces
        definitions = sorted(
            self.definitions.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True
        )

        for (word, value) in definitions:
            expr = expr.replace(word, str(value))

        if all(c in SAFE_CHARS for c in char):
            value = eval(expr)
        else:
            value = "unknown"

        return self.values.get(value, "unknown")


if __name__ == "__main__":

    calc = Calculator()
    for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
        if not (line := line.strip()):
            continue
        if line.startswith("def"):
            _, name, value = line.split()
            calc.definition(name, float(value))
        elif line.startswith("calc") and line.endswith("="):
            _, expr = line[:-1].split("calc")
            print(f"{line} {calc.calculate(expr)}")
        elif line.startswith("clear"):
            calc.clear()
```

Assuming that `eval` is off the table, I would probably rewrite it as follows. Due note that we use a recursive algorithm just for fun to evaluate the expressions. A lot of care is taken to correctly handle deeply nested expressions.

```
import sys


def is_number(s: str) -> bool:
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


class Calculator:
    def __init__(self):
        self.definitions = dict()
        self.values = dict()

    def definition(self, name: str, integer: float) -> None:
        self.definitions[name] = integer
        self.values[integer] = name

    def clear(self):
        self.definitions = dict()
        self.values = dict()

    def calculate(self, expr: str) -> float | str:
        expr = "".join(expr.split())  # Remove all spaces
        try:
            value = self._eval(expr)
        except KeyError:
            value = "unknown"
        return self.values.get(value, "unknown")

    def _eval(self, expr: str) -> float:
        """self.evaluates an expression consisting of binary expressions

        >>> calculator._eval("123.5")
        123.5
        >>> calculator._eval("(5 + 3) + (1 + (2 + 6))")
        17.0
        >>> calculator._eval("((((5))+(2))+1+2)")
        10.0
        """
        if is_number(expr):
            return float(expr)
        if "(" in expr:
            start, stop = inner_expression(expr)
            new_expr = self._eval(expr[start + 1 : stop - 1])
            expr = expr.replace(expr[start:stop], str(new_expr))
            return self._eval(expr)
        elif "+" in expr:
            expr_1, expr_2 = expr.split("+", 1)
            return self._eval(expr_1) + self._eval(expr_2)
        elif "-" in expr:
            expr_1, expr_2 = expr.split("-", 1)
            return self._eval(expr_1) - self._eval(expr_2)
        elif "/" in expr:
            expr_1, expr_2 = expr.split("/", 1)
            return self._eval(expr_1) / self._eval(expr_2)
        elif "*" in expr:
            expr_1, expr_2 = expr.split("*", 1)
            return self._eval(expr_1) * self._eval(expr_2)
        elif "^" in expr:
            expr_1, expr_2 = expr.split("^", 1)
            return self._eval(expr_1) ** self._eval(expr_2)
        return self.definitions[expr]


MATCHING_BRACKET = {")": "(", "}": "{", "[": "]"}
OPEN_BRACKETS = set(["(", "{", "["])


def inner_expression(expr: str):
    """Returns the indices for the inner most expression

    >>> inner_expression("(5}")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ValueError: Incompatible brackets '}' does not match '('!

    >>> inner_expression("((5)")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ValueError: Incomplete brackets found, the brackets ['('] was never closed!

    >>> a, b = inner_expression('((5+2)+(1+2))'); '((5+2)+(1+2))'[a:b]
    '(5+2)'

    >>> a, b = inner_expression('((((5))+(2))+1+2)'); '((((5))+(2))+1+2)'[a:b]
    '(5)'
    """
    stack = []
    deepest_nesting = start = 0
    indices = None
    for i, char in enumerate(expr):
        if char in MATCHING_BRACKET:
            if stack[-1] != MATCHING_BRACKET[char]:
                raise ValueError(
                    f"Incompatible brackets '{char}' does not match '{stack[-1]}'!"
                )
            if (nesting := len(stack)) > deepest_nesting:
                deepest_nesting = nesting
                indices = (start, i + 1)
            stack.pop()
        elif char in OPEN_BRACKETS:
            stack.append(char)
            start = i
    if stack:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Incomplete brackets found, the brackets {stack} was never closed!"
        )
    return indices if indices is not None else (0, len(expr))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod(extraglobs={"calculator": Calculator()})

    calc = Calculator()
    for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
        if not (line := line.strip()):
            continue
        if line.startswith("def"):
            _, name, value = line.split()
            calc.definition(name, float(value))
        elif line.startswith("calc") and line.endswith("="):
            _, expr = line[:-1].split("calc")
            print(f"{line} {calc.calculate(expr)}")
        elif line.startswith("clear"):
            calc.clear()
```

EDIT: If we allow ourselves to use the full capabilities of Python, disregarding that our code must be beginner friendly we can do as shown below

- Reduce was introduced to reduce the number of recursive calls and offer a small speed improvement. Our original code reduced the expression as follows `a + b + c + d + e` = `a + (b + c + d+ e)` = `a a + (b + (c + d + e))` usw.
- The operators were extracted into a seperate function reducing this

  ```
        elif "+" in expr:
            expr_1, expr_2 = expr.split("+", 1)
            return self._eval(expr_1) + self._eval(expr_2)
        elif "-" in expr:
            expr_1, expr_2 = expr.split("-", 1)
            return self._eval(expr_1) - self._eval(expr_2)
        elif "/" in expr:
            expr_1, expr_2 = expr.split("/", 1)
            return self._eval(expr_1) / self._eval(expr_2)
        elif "*" in expr:
            expr_1, expr_2 = expr.split("*", 1)
            return self._eval(expr_1) * self._eval(expr_2)
        elif "^" in expr:
            expr_1, expr_2 = expr.split("^", 1)
            return self._eval(expr_1) ** self._eval(expr_2)
        return self.definitions[expr]
  ```

  into this

  ```
    for operator, function in OPERATORS.items():
        if operator not in expr:
            continue
        expressions = map(self._eval, expr.split(operator))
        return reduce(function, expressions)
  ```
- Minor cleanup for the `inner_expression` as well
- A bit more typing hints and doctests

#### Code without imports

```
import sys


def is_number(s: str) -> bool:
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


OPERATORS = {
    "+": lambda x, y: x + y,
    "-": lambda x, y: x - y,
    "/": lambda x, y: x / y,
    "*": lambda x, y: x * y,
    "^": lambda x, y: x**y,
}


def reduce(function, iterable, initializer=None):
    """Implements the reduce function without external modules

    >>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, range(5))
    10
    >>> reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, range(5), initializer=100)
    110
    >>> reduce(lambda x, y: f"({x}) + {y}", range(5))
    '((((0) + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4'
    >>> reduce(lambda x, y: f"({x}) + {y}", range(5), initializer=100)
    '(((((100) + 0) + 1) + 2) + 3) + 4'
    """
    it = iter(iterable)
    if initializer is None:
        value = next(it)
    else:
        value = initializer
    for element in it:
        value = function(value, element)
    return value


class Calculator:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.definitions = dict()
        self.values = dict()

    def definition(self, name: str, integer: float) -> None:
        self.definitions[name] = integer
        self.values[integer] = name

    def clear(self) -> None:
        self.definitions = dict()
        self.values = dict()

    def calculate(self, expr: str) -> float | str:
        expr = "".join(expr.split())  # Remove all spaces
        try:
            value = self._eval(expr)
        except KeyError:
            value = "unknown"
        return self.values.get(value, "unknown")

    def _eval(self, expr: str) -> float:
        """self.evaluates an expression consisting of binary expressions

        >>> qalc._eval("123.5")
        123.5
        >>> qalc._eval("(5 + 3) + (1 + (2 + 6))")
        17.0
        >>> qalc._eval("((((5))+(2))+1+2)")
        10.0
        """
        if is_number(expr):
            return float(expr)

        if "(" in expr:
            start, stop = inner_expression(expr)
            new_expr = self._eval(expr[start + 1 : stop - 1])
            expr = expr.replace(expr[start:stop], str(new_expr))
            return self._eval(expr)

        for operator, function in OPERATORS.items():
            if operator not in expr:
                continue
            expressions = map(self._eval, expr.split(operator))
            return reduce(function, expressions)

        return self.definitions[expr]


MATCHING_BRACKET = {")": "(", "}": "{", "[": "]"}
OPEN_BRACKETS = set(["(", "{", "["])


def inner_expression(expr: str) -> tuple[int, int]:
    """Returns the indices for the inner most expression

    >>> inner_expression("(5}")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ValueError: Incompatible brackets '}' does not match '('!
    >>> inner_expression("((5)")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    ValueError: Incomplete brackets found, the brackets ['('] was never closed!
    >>> a, b = inner_expression('((5+2)+(1+2))'); '((5+2)+(1+2))'[a:b]
    '(5+2)'
    >>> a, b = inner_expression('((((5))+(2))+1+2)'); '((((5))+(2))+1+2)'[a:b]
    '(5)'
    """
    stack = []
    deepest_nesting = start = 0
    indices = None
    for i, char in enumerate(expr):

        if char in OPEN_BRACKETS:
            stack.append(char)
            start = i
            continue
        elif char not in MATCHING_BRACKET:
            continue

        matching_brackets = stack[-1] == MATCHING_BRACKET[char]

        if not matching_brackets:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Incompatible brackets '{char}' does not match '{stack[-1]}'!"
            )

        if (nesting := len(stack)) > deepest_nesting:
            deepest_nesting = nesting
            indices = (start, i + 1)
        stack.pop()

    if stack:
        raise ValueError(
            f"Incomplete brackets found, the brackets {stack} was never closed!"
        )

    if indices is None:
        return (0, len(expr))
    return indices


def first_and_remaining(line: str) -> tuple[str, str | None]:
    """If lines = 'a b c' this returns ('a', 'b c')

    >>> first_and_remaining('a b c')
    ('a', 'b c')
    >>> first_and_remaining('')
    ('', None)
    >>> first_and_remaining(' a ')
    ('a', None)
    >>> first_and_remaining(' a b ')
    ('a', 'b')
    """
    if " " not in (stripped := line.strip()):
        return stripped, None
    return tuple(x.strip() for x in stripped.split(maxsplit=1))


def calculator(lines, calc=None) -> None:
    """Feeds lines into a calculator

    >>> commands = '''
    ... def foo 3
    ... calc foo + bar =
    ... def bar 7
    ... def programming 10
    ... calc foo + bar =
    ... def is 4
    ... def fun 8
    ... calc programming - is + fun =
    ... def fun 1
    ... calc programming - is + fun =
    ... clear'''
    >>> calculator(commands.splitlines())
    calc foo + bar = unknown
    calc foo + bar = programming
    calc programming - is + fun = unknown
    calc programming - is + fun = bar
    """
    if calc is None:
        calc = Calculator()

    for command, expression in map(first_and_remaining, lines):

        if not command:
            continue

        if expression is None:
            if command == "clear":
                calc.clear()
            continue

        if command == "def":
            name, value = expression.split()
            calc.definition(name, int(value))

        elif command == "calc" and expression.endswith("="):
            value = calc.calculate(expression[:-1])
            print(f"{command} {expression} {value}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest

    doctest.testmod(extraglobs={"qalc": Calculator()})

    calculator(sys.stdin.readlines())
```